# Why is nickel affinity chromatography not used in production of proteins for clinical purposes?

Tags: chromatography

Is there a reason why this specific method of chromatography is not used for extracting proteins that will be used for clinical purposes? I saw an article saying that it could be used in many other biological applications, but my professor told me that it's not used in the specified cases above. What would be the reason for being so? Is it a problem of costs?